# Auto install angular library's dependencies

Tags: angular, ng-packagr, angular-library

We are working on a shared widget library `@acme/widget-collection` which is a collection of all widgets developed internally as separate modules - `@acme/widget1`, `@acme/widget2` and so on.

This should allow developers that need to use the widgets to simply import the `@acme/widget-collection` instead of needing to import all widgets separately.

So the library named `@acme/widget-collection` imports `@acme/widget1`, `@acme/widget2` and `@acme/widget3` and, of course, then export them so they are made available when importing `@acme/widget-collection`.

In the shared library, we define all the widgets as `peerDependencies` in `package.json`.

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "@acme/widget1": "^0.0.1",
    "@acme/widget2": "^0.0.1",
    "@acme/widget3": "^0.0.1"
  }
```

After importing the `@acme/widgets-collection` library into a project, when running or building the project, we are getting the following error - `error TS2307: Cannot find module @acme/widget1`.

If we manually install the dependencies i.e. `npm i @acme/widget1 @acme/widget2 @acme/widget3` it then works fine.

However, we are trying to avoid manually installing all dependencies of `@acme/widget-collections` since these keep on changing and we want npm to install them automatically.

Running `npm i @acme/widget-collection` does not seem to install them.

Is there an npm native way to install the dependencies?

If not, should they be installed using `ng-packagr` directly into the `@acme/widget-collection/node_modules` folder?

**UPDATE**

Entering the dependencies as "dependencies" instead of "peerDependencies" seem to install them automatically when running `npm i @acme/widget-collection` but I am not sure if this is the recommended way, as most angular examples I've seen use `peerDependencies`.
This seem to work:

```
"dependencies": {
        "@acme/widget1": "^0.0.1",
        "@acme/widget2": "^0.0.1",
        "@acme/widget3": "^0.0.1"
      }
```

And running `npm i` or `npm i @acme/widget-collection` will install `@acme/widget1`, `@acme/widget2` and `@acme/widget3` in `node_modules` folder.

Comment: Running `npm i @widget-collection` wouldn't install `@acme/widget-collection`. Do you mean to run `npm i @acme/widget-collection`?

Comment: @R.Richards yes, updated the question. Thanks

Comment: You will need to whitelist them when you build the library as well.

Comment: @gearsandcode thanks that's what I've been doing since I posted the question, do you know if they need to be under dependencies or peerDependencies?

Comment: @Yani - peerDependencies, however they won't be automatically installed and you'll have to manually add them to the consuming app. The auto-install of peerDependencies was dropped in npm v3.